# Flutter || W/DynamiteModule( 4887): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

When I fetch data from Firebase Firestore, data is not shown. And it gives me this problem. Is it related to Firebase or anything else?

```
W/DynamiteModule( 4887): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule( 4887): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 4887): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
W/ProviderInstaller( 4887): Failed to report request stats: com.google.android.gms.common.security.ProviderInstallerImpl.reportRequestStats [class android.content.Context, long, long]
```

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible code.

Comment: I am really stuck on this here

Comment: have u solved this yet? update pls.

Answer (score 2):

Add Permission to `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` and then try.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no predefined solution to this issue which you are having. However, I suggest you try the following steps:

- Most of the time, outdated Google Play services can cause these
  warnings, so the recommendation is to **update Google Play services**.
- Make sure that **<uses-permissionandroid:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> is defined in all the
  three AndroidManifest.xml files** that i.e debug/main/profile.

  For some cases, having **<usespermissionandroid:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  in main
  AndroidManifest file** also helps.
- If you are running your **app on an older device** make sure that
  **multi-dex is enabled**.
- It may also happen due to **insufficient storage**. Hence, **clear the app
  data from settings**.
- Use the **latest Firebase plugins**.

You may also refer to the [Github link](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/issues/164).

Comment: It does not help me

Comment: Can you share the minimal reproducible code?

Comment: i changed `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'` to  `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'`  in android\build.gradle or try latest classpath as your document priority .in my case flutter firestore

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and haven't found any solution. What I can tell you is that this bug only happens in debug mode.If you run the application with the command `flutter run --release -v`, this bug won't appear.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem android emulator pixel 4 API 31 Flutter

I added this permission

```
<usespermissionandroid:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

it worked the first time but in another build, it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and wasted a lot of time trying to solve it. It turned out the String of collectionPath in Flutter's code is not match the String of collection in Firestore :(

Answer (score 0):

Besides adding the permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I added these Google Play Services dependencies in the `android/app/build.gradle` file:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.6.0'
```

Made a '**flutter pub ge**t' in the console.
And all my Dynamite warnings were over.