# accessing hidden in flutter and Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found

Tags: flutter

hello I can this error running my flutter app when reading data from firebase here is the error :

```
W/DynamiteModule( 6937): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule( 6937): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 6937): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite 
found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
I/example.thrift( 6937): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/example.thrift( 6937): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
V/NativeCrypto( 6937): Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 295 native methods...
W/example.thrift( 6937): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->getCurveName()Ljava/lang/String; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
I/ProviderInstaller( 6937): Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
W/example.thrift( 6937): Accessing hidden field Ljava/net/Socket;->impl:Ljava/net/SocketImpl; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/example.thrift( 6937): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/example.thrift( 6937): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->open(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/example.thrift( 6937): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->setCurveName(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/example.thrift( 6937): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard;->getThreadPolicy()Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard$Policy; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/example.thrift( 6937): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard$Policy;->onNetwork()V (greylist, linking, allowed)
```

here is androidmanifest.xml/main:

`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.th">
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:label="th"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
```

`

any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter || W/DynamiteModule( 4887): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70820069/flutter-w-dynamitemodule-4887-local-module-descriptor-class-for-com-google)

Comment: Your manifest does not seem to include an INTERNET permission. Add it before the ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission

Comment: thank you it works but what about the accessing :

Comment: W/example.thrift( 8573): Accessing hidden field Ljava/net/Socket;->impl:Ljava/net/SocketImpl; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/example.thrift( 8573): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)